# Voltage at the drain of P-channel part of IRF7319

Tags: mosfet, switching, powermosfet

Given the switch schematic:

[image: Schematic]

When I applied 5V to VCC and pressed SW1, I measured 4.8V on the drain of Q1B.

With SW1 released, I measured 1.85V on the drain of Q1B.

I read that power MOSFETs require at least a 10V differential to fully function, so I increased VCC to 12V.

Now, with SW1 pressed, I measured 11.45V on the drain Q1B.

After releasing SW1, I measured 1.96V on the drain of Q1B.

Shouldn't it be more like 0V?

I've tried to isolate the P-channel in the chip as follows:

[image: Reduced schematic]

And at the drain, I still see around 2V.

Am I missing something, or is my IRF7319 busted?

Comment: The [datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRF7319-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf) specifies a max Drain-Source leakage current of 1uA (although that's at 24V). What voltage drop would you expect to  see across your resistor + LED with 1uA flowing through them?

Comment: I'm not sure. The LED is a standard red 5mm one. I don't have a datasheet for it. However, I measured the current flowing through the resistor and LED, and it is about 400uA for 5V and 1100uA for 12V.

Comment: Can you measure the voltage between the drain and GND for the N channel MOSFET as well?

Comment: But your P-channel MOSFET is OFF (PMOS alone circuit). To be able to turn ON the P-channel MOSFET you need to connect the gate terminal to GND and the source to VCC. And this 2V you are seeing pon DVM is normal becomes of the LED. And the P-Channel MOSFET is OFF because the gate is at Vcc together with the source.

Comment: Thanks, I think I now understand what is going on :) Unfortunately, I'm quite sure I've just destroyed this chip because I just saw magic smoke come out :P